# Split Pandas Dataframe Into Sub Dataframes (not list of dataframes)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split a dataframe into as many different dataframes as possible, and set the name of the new dataframe based on information being split.

EX:

call this dataframe 'df'

```
Name    ID    Number    Code    Name2
123     cp1    500      ABC      456
123     cp1    501      DEF      456
```

I am trying to split this dataframe into chunks based on 'Number', and then rename these new dataframes accordingly.

The result would look like the following:

```
df500:
Name    ID    Number    Code    Name2
123     cp1    500      ABC      456

df501:
Name    ID    Number    Code    Name2
123     cp1    501      DEF      456
```

Does pandas allow for something like this to be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a dictionary by grouping:

```
d={'df_{}'.format(i):g for i,g in df.groupby('Number')}
```

---

```
{'df_500':    Name   ID  Number Code  Name2
 0   123  cp1     500  ABC  456.0, 'df_501':    Name   ID  Number Code  Name2
 1   123  cp1     501  DEF    NaN}
```

---

You can then call the keys of the dict like:

```
print(d['df_500'])
```

---

```
   Name   ID  Number Code  Name2
0   123  cp1     500  ABC  456.0
```

Comment: is it possible to alter the naming convention so that each dataframe name is a combination of Number AND Name?

Comment: currently a dataframe name would be `df_(Number)`, is it possible to make it `df_(Number)+(Name)`?

Comment: I do not wish to change the way the data is grouped, only the way the dataframes are named.

Comment: @MaxB `{'df_'+str(i)+'_'+str(g.Name.iat[0]):g for i,g in df.groupby('Number')}` ?